# (Django) Problem installing fixture 'rules.json': 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: json, django, django-fixtures

I'm trying to populate my db with fixtures with the next command:

> python .\manage.py loaddata .\rules\fixtures\rules.json

But I get the next error:

> AttributeError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\Ángel -
> Trabajo\Documents\AVC.\rules\fixtures\rules.json': 'NoneType' object
> has no attribute 'id'

This is my model:

```
class Rule(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición de modelo para Reglas"""

    FIELDS = [
        ('user_name', 'Nombre de usuario'),
        ('user_code', 'Codigo de usuario')
    ]

    string = models.CharField("Cadena de referencia", max_length=100, null=False, default="", blank=False)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=False, default=None, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    license = models.ForeignKey(License, null=False, default=None, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    field = models.CharField("Campo objetivo", max_length=50, default='nombre_usuario', choices=FIELDS)
    include = models.BooleanField("Incluye", null=False, default=True)
    order = models.IntegerField("Orden", null=True, default=None)
    uppercase_sensitive = models.BooleanField("Sensible a las mayúsculas", null=False, default=False)
    dateadded = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de inserción", default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And this is my json:

```
[
    {
        "model":"rules.rule",
        "pk":null,
        "fields":{
            "string": "DINAMITZADORA",
            "profile": "1",
            "license": "1",
            "field": "user_name",
            "include": "1",
            "order": "0",
            "uppercase_sensitive": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"rules.rule",
        "pk":null,
        "fields":{
            "string": "adm",
            "profile": "1",
            "license": "1",
            "field": "user_name",
            "include": "1",
            "order": "0",
            "uppercase_sensitive": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"rules.rule",
        "pk":null,
        "fields":{
            "string": "admin",
            "profile": "1",
            "license": "1",
            "field": "user_name",
            "include": "1",
            "order": "0",
            "uppercase_sensitive": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"rules.rule",
        "pk":null,
        "fields":{
            "string": "alum",
            "profile": "1",
            "license": "1",
            "field": "user_name",
            "include": "1",
            "order": "0",
            "uppercase_sensitive": "0"
        }
    },
]
```

I've tried declare the FIXTURE_DIRS in my settings.py but didnt work.
I tried to let only one element (it has like 80) in json just in case it was about some value but it didnt work neither.

I'm completly lost, could you help me?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Why have your fixture objects got `null` values for their IDs?

Comment: I've read that if you write null it just assign an autoincremental number

Answer (score 1):

Did you type this json yourself?

How i do it, i start with a clean database and than i add some data via the web interface and than i execute the following command:

```
python .\manage.py dumpdata your_appname --indent 4 > .\rules\fixtures\rules.json
```

So later on when you have an empty database you can use your command to load the data again:

```
python .\manage.py loaddata .\rules\fixtures\rules.json
```

If you specify a path after `loaddata`, than `FIXTURE_DIRS` will be ignored so you should not set that in your `settings.py` file.

Best practice for saving your fixtures is in the location `your_app/fixtures/somename.json` But i assume this is the case since i think your app is called rules?

If you do this django will know where to look and you can just type instead of providing the whole path.

```
python .\manage.py loaddata some_name.json
```